# Scroller style changes for scrollbar

Tags: css, overflow

I have a scroller with scrollbar whose edges are not rounded.
I want to make the edges of the scroller rounded, so that it sits inside the div.
the scroller should be inside the blue rounded shadow as shown in image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CssJ6.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you  round the edges of the scroller using CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

If that isn't what you're looking for:

[Learn how to create a custom scrollbar with CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp)

Comment: `::-webkit-scrollbar-track` works, but we have to add `::-webkit-scrollbar` also to be able to add other pseudo classes for scrollbar. But I don't want to add any styles inside `::-webkit-scrollbar`, and don't want to change its default behaviour.What can be done in that case